# (bash scripting) How to sort the lines that are in a position multiple of 'n' in a file?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, scripting

I have to program a script in ubuntu linux in bash language, which has to take three arguments in the command line: first the name of the file whose lines I have to sort, second a letter ('a' if I want to sort alphabetically ascending or 'z' if I want to sort alphabetically descending) and third a positive number 'n'. I have to sort only the lines that are multiple of 'n'. For example, if I have a text file with 100 lines and n=5, then I have to sort only the lines 5,10,15, ..., 100 and the rest must remain untouched. Can this be done?
I can find and sort the lines that are multiple of 'n' like this:

```
awk "NR%$n==0" archivo.txt | sort -f
```

but now I don't know how to write these lines into the file again.

Thanks for the attention

Comment: Show us what you have so far.

Comment: I can find the lines that are multiple of 'n' and sort them like this:                                                  awk "NR%$n==0" file.txt | sort -f                                                                              but now I cannot reintroduce these lines again into the file.

Comment: FYI, that would be better written as `awk -v n="$n" 'NR % n == 0'`; using string substitution to generate scripts (in any language -- not just awk, but also bash, SQL, etc) is patently insecure, as opposed to passing data out-of-band from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use gawk if you don't mind throwing the entire input file into memory so the subset of lines can be sorted before being printed.

```
#!/usr/bin/env gawk -f

BEGIN {
  if (!inc) inc=5              # set a default
}

NR%inc {
  # This is a normal line
  nosort[NR]=$0
  next
}

{
  # This is an increment of "inc"
  tosort[NR]=$0
}

END {
  # Sort the array of increments
  asort(tosort)

  # Step through our two arrays, picking what to print based on the modulo
  n=0
  for (i=1; i<NR; i++)
    if (i%inc==0)
      print tosort[++n]
    else
      print nosort[i]
}
```

You might run this with something like:

```
$ ./sortthing -v inc=5 inputfile
```

Note that this uses the gawk function `asort()`, which does not exist in One True Awk. So if you're doing this on *BSD or OS X, you may need to install additional tools.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Doubtless this could be done in pure `awk` as well, but the below uses native bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

input=${1:-archivo.txt} # set input to $1, or default to archivo.txt
n=${2:-5}               # set n to $2, or default to 5
i=0                     # initialize line counter to 0

while IFS= read -r line <&3; do  # always read from input on FD 3
  if (( i % n == 0 )); then      # if we're on a line being sorted...
    IFS= read -r line <&4        # ...overwrite $line from the awk | sort process on FD 4
  fi
  printf '%s\n' "$line"          # write out whatever we most recently read 
  (( ++i ))                      # increment line counter 
done 3<"$input" 4< <(awk -v "n=$n" 'NR%n==0' <"$input" | sort -f)
```

---

Some notes:

- Using a shebang explicitly invoking `bash` (not `sh`) at the first line of the script ensures that extensions are available.
- `<(awk ...)` is a process substitution -- it evaluates to a filename which, when read, will provide the output of the `awk` command. `4<` connects the contents of that file to file descriptor #4.
- `(( ))` creates an arithmetic context, and is an extension provided by ksh and bash (as compared to `$(( ))`, which is guaranteed by POSIX).
- For details on why `read` is being called the way it is (with `IFS` cleared and the `-r` argument passed), see [BashFAQ #001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).
- Using `awk -v "var=$var" 'awk script using var'` avoids bugs and injection vulnerabilities that can be caused when forming scripts with string concatenation

Comment: That code do not work, maybe it has a mistake but I can not find it

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I see you are using a redirection instead of the `-u` option of `read` (for portability I think).  If the shell is Bash, are there any advantages/drawbacks to using `-u`?

Comment: @Fred, no drawback, just no particular advantage to it, and I prefer to lean on bashisms only when they provide some advantage (even if that advantage is simply clarity). By using a different syntax to redirect input for `read` than that used for other purposes, I'd argue that `read -u` *reduces* clarity rather than increasing it.

Comment: @SergioRey, if instead of "doesn't work" you described *how* it fails -- is the output wrong? If so, precisely in what way? Is there a message? If so, exactly what? -- that would be far more useful.

Comment: @grail, see my response to Fred above.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  In my case, I use aliases to initiate `while` loops in my scripts in the exact same way all the time, so the `-u` option is the only one usable in an alias.